# Effect on battery characteristics of a zinc-air button cell from oxygen starvation?

Tags: batteries

How would the performance of a zinc-air battery would be impacted by oxygen starvation - a sealed container with the available oxygen gradually decreasing over time.

Would this just decrease the maximum available current or would there also be a drop in voltage?

I am wondering if there could be some way of deriving changes in oxygen levels inside the container based just on the battery characteristics.

Comment: Sounds like a fun experiment.  I expect it'll have to be a small container, though.

Comment: I'm stuck waiting till tomorrow for shops to open before I can experiment - goal is to detect when something like a ziplock bag is opened.

Comment: Ah.  You're going to remove the air, then detect when the baggie is opened.  That'll probably work better than what I was thinking about.  I was going the other way - sealed container with air in it and an oxygen consuming process and you wanted to monitor the oxygen level.

Comment: It's part way between the two - baggie gets sealed with some air still in it. A sliver of nichrome heats up a bead of some chemical or another that reacts to scavenge the majority of the oxygen causing the performance of the battery to drop. Once the baggie is opened whoosh comes the fresh oxygen, battery comes good again and the intrusion is detected.

Comment: Do you put the battery monitor in the baggie? If so what powers the monitor?

Comment: The theory is the atmosphere is depleted just enough to have an impact on performance but still function

Comment: Ziploc bag is probably still quite porous to oxygen anyway. Could be an interesting experiment.

Comment: Reading up on electro-galvanic oxygen sensors (used to monitor diver O2 in rebreather) at the moment which seem to be based on same idea I was thinking except they use lead--air instead of zinc for some reason I haven't discovered yet.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out zinc-air button cell batteries can be utilized as oxygen sensors by monitoring the current and voltage characteristics when driving a load as indicated in the two related patents below - there has also been an academic study done on effects of low oxygen environment to zinc-air batteries but I do not have access [IEEE paywalled paper: Oxygen consumption of zinc-air batteries and their performance at low oxygen concentration levels](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8600972) (if someone with access is able to summarize the finding in the comments I would be most grateful) :

[Patent US6758962B1: Oxygen sensing](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6099707)

> Oxygen concentration measurement is carried out over a broad range by an instrument utilizing a zinc-air cell having a lower-than-nominal potential difference imposed across its electrodes by a shunt branch incorporating the source-drain circuit of a field effect transistor (FET). A feedback circuit is used to improve linearity of the output and cell life without sacrificing the broad dynamic range achieved by the use of the FET shunt branch.

[Patent US6099707A: Apparatus for sensing oxygen concentration](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6099707)

> An apparatus and method for sensing a concentration of oxygen in a flow of gas in a breathing circuit for a patient. A biasing voltage is provided across a zinc-air cell so that the zinc-air cell produces a current having a magnitude, wherein the magnitude of the current corresponds to the concentration of oxygen in the gas.